# copy VHD from one Storage account to another Storage account in different Tenant

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I would need your suggestions to move one of our Application server created using un-managed disks which is around 15 TB of disk space. We have a requirement to move the VM from one Azure AD Tenant (Source) to another Tenant (Destination). However we have to keep Source VM "as is" until we check the data integrity post move. In order to achieve this I plan to move VHDs (15 x 1 TB each) to Destination Storage account.

What bandwidth I would need to copy 15 TB. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong. You need to take the snapshot of the VM what uses un-managed disk and move it to another destination. Question in mind, do you need this snapshot to be managed or un-managed and you will copy it to the destination storage account?

There is several approaches, please review:

**[First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-powershell-sample-copy-managed-disks-vhd):**

> 1. Create a disk snapshot by using the GUI (Portal) or PowerShell:
>    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk
> 2. Load the Windows PowerShell.
> 3. Run following commands:
>    #Install the latest Az PowerShell module.
>
> Get-InstalledModule -Name Az -AllVersions
>
> #Connect to the Azure Account:  Connect-AzAccount
>
> #Declare Variables:
>
> $resourceGroupName ='' $snapshotName
> ='' $resourceGroupNameStorageAccount =''
> $storageAccountName =''
> $storageContainerName ='' $destinationVHDFileName =''
>
> #Get the Storage Account Key of the Destination Storage Account $storageAccountKey  = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName
> $resourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName
>
> #Generate the SAS for the snapshot $sas = Grant-AzSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName -Access 'Read' -DurationInSecond 6000;
>
> #Create the context of the destination storage account for the snapshot $destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext
> –storageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey
> ($storageAccountKey).Value[0]
>
> #Copy the snapshot to the destination Storage Account
> Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer
> $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob
> "$destinationVHDFileName.vhd"

**Second:**

Use the azcopy to copy the snapshot. That also will allow you to see the progress. - **Highly recommend to use that approach.**

To do it:

1. Download the tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json
2. Use "azcopy copy" command to copy the snapshot to the Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#copy-containers-directories-and-blobs

**Syntax:**

```
azcopy copy 'https://<source-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<SAS-token>' 'https://<destination-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/' --recursive
```

**Example:**

```
azcopy copy 'https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-07-04T05:30:08Z&st=2019-07-03T21:30:08Z&spr=https&sig=CAfhgnc9gdGktvB=ska7bAiqIddM845yiyFwdMH481QA8%3D' 'https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net' --recursive
```

[image]

As far as I know there's no data limitation on the amount of inbound/outbound data between Storage Accounts.

Do note that outbound data transfers cost, while inbound are for free:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/

Additional resources for you to use:

- [Scalability and performance targets for VM disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-scalability-targets#unmanaged-virtual-machine-disks)
- [Scale targets for standard storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#scale-targets-for-standard-storage-accounts)
- [Azure Latency Test](https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency)

Comment: Thank you Olga. I would like my destination Storage account would be managed.

Comment: @Sri Sai, second approach should work for you.

Comment: Thank you. And One more question. How can i see the current progress of my azcopy.

Comment: You should be able to see the progress while using the AzCopy. As example, output above in the image what I posted.